# Firebase auth customClaims not exists for user created with help of createCustomToken()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I want to store some secret data in user' `customClaims`. I create a token on server with:

`var customToken = createCustomToken(uniqueId,  {mySecretData:"VerySecretData"})`,

sending it to my app , logging user in with `signInWithCustomToken(customToken)`, and it works fine,

BUT, when i am fetching user later on server by calling admin's `getUser(uniqueId)` and trying to see its `customClaims` there is nothing, undefined.

The interesting thing is that i do see this secret data in callable function context' auth property' `token` object.

Question: why `developerClaims` are not user' `customClaims` ?

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#createcustomtoken

Comment: It sounds like you're mixing up custom tokens and custom claims.  They're not directly related to each other.  Custom claims can only be read and written as shown in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code of what you're trying to do when getting the user with the Admin SDK.

Comment: @DougStevenson and what can i do with the developerClaims stored in the custom token? can i turn them to customClaims somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claims added via `createCustomToken()` only exist in the Auth token issued by the Firebase Auth. They are not stored anywhere beyond that, and `getUser()` response will not include them. You should use the `setCustomUserClaims()` to get the behavior you've indicated.